# How to reset cname on github?

Tags: github, dns, repository, cname, github-pages

I recently added a cname file to my repository to have a custom domain. Today i deleted the cname file hoping it would revert back to original but it keeps redirecting to the domain specified in cname file.

I want to reset my github page to username.github.io from the custom domain it gets redirected to.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've already deleted the `CNAME` file and pushed that change to GitHub you just need to wait. This change can take some time to go into effect.